# Connection two subnets behind routers

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

***Task is very peculiar. I ask your help. Do you have any ideas on this subject.***

We have:

1.First device:

|Internet| -> |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 1| -> |Server base on Ubuntu 1|

2.Second device:

|Internet| -> |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 2| -> |Server base on Ubuntu 2|

Distance between them nearly 100-150 meters.

**Task:** We need get "controller UniFi" which control two wifi point Ubiquiti UniFi AP Outdoor. (http://www.lanmart.ru/blogs/ubiquiti-unifi-outdoor_obzor-i-nastrojka/)
First wifi point ("UniFi 1") connected on |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 1|.
Second wifi point ("UniFi 2") connected on |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 2|.

"Controller UniFi" **MUST BE** in the same subnet as the access points UniFi, that controller to manage.

"Controller UniFi" is a software program which installed on |Server base on Ubuntu 1| and work on apache and java. It is web-site for control.

**We need access point "UniFi 2" connected on subnet whith "Controller UniFi".**

Is it possible to configure vpn-server on |Server base on Ubuntu 1| with vnp-client on |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 2| to take connection subnet behind first router |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 1| with network behind |ASUS RT-N16(firmware dd-wrt) 2|???

Access points UniFi do not support vpn-client.

Thank`s.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but still sharing a solution if it may help anyone

You can use Ubuntu1 as controller without any VPn configuration. Just configure dd-wrt to do port forwarding for ports 8081,8080,8443,8880,8843,27117 to ubuntu1

Now using ssh add dd-rt1 1's IP as controller IP